# Empty second ctor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
data class UserRto(val lastName: String, val firstName: String, val email: String, val password: String) {
    constructor() : this("", "", "", "")
}
```

Is this the easiest way to get a second ctor without arguments (for json desrialization)?

Comment: It is possible you are asking the wrong question, and XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/) ... Did you want to ask "How do I deserialize JSON for a Kotlin data class that does not have a default empty constructor?"  If so, I added an answer for that below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a convention (just for that case :) that a parameterless constructor is generated if all parameters have default values:

```
//Kotlin
data class UserRto(val lastName: String = "",
                   val firstName: String = "",
                   val email: String = "",
                   val password: String = "")

//Java
new UserRto();
new UserRto("a", "a", "a", "a");
```

Your solution with an explicit empty constructor has an advantage that all parameters must be provided, or non. But it is not a big deal in most cases and it is rarely used.

Answer (score 3):

You do not specify which JSON deserialization library you are using.  It is likely that you do not need this secondary constructor at all and can work directly with the class constructor that contains all of the properties as parameters.

- For Jackson, use the [Jackson-Kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) which automatically handles all of Kotlins unqiue cases including ability to call a constructor or factory with all of the parameters being properties (and in 2.8.x this includes default values for parameters being used for missing properties in the JSON)
- For Gson, I think [Kotson](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/Kotson) might do the same.

Google might find others for these or other libraries as well.

Then you would only need:

```
data class UserRto(val lastName: String, val firstName: String, val email: String, val password: String)
```

And with the Jackson-Kotlin module you would simply:

```
val user: UserRto = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString)
```